# Qt Объединение ячеек в таблице

Tags: c++, qt

Всем привет! Хочу сделать таблицу как на прикрепленной картинке: [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Использую для этого QT классы: QTextCursor, QTextDocument, QTextTable

Так вот у меня `проблема с объединением ячеек как на картинке`. Сейчас `мой код рисует все без объединений`, как в 5 6 7 столбцах.

Как понял у QTextTable есть метод `splitCell()`, но пока не понял, как его лучше впихнуть в мою реализацию, чтобы достичь нужного результата.

Видимо придется добавлять в функцию addTableText аргумент со списком строк которые нужно объединять при определенном условии?

Код функций прикрепил ниже:

Функция добавления таблицы и заполнение заголовков таблицы:

```
placeTable(QList<QString> headers)
{
    int lines = 1;
    cursor.movePosition(QTextCursor::End);

    cursor.insertTable(lines, headers.count(), tableHeaderStyle.tableStyle);
    freeTableLines = lines;

    for (int i=0; i<headers.size(); i++)
    {
        cursor.setBlockFormat(tableHeaderStyle.parStyle);
        cursor.insertText(headers[i], tableHeaderStyle.textStyle);
        cursor.movePosition(QTextCursor::NextCell);
    }

    freeTableLines--;
}
```

Функция добавления текста в колонки таблицы:

```
addTableText(QList<QString> content, RWStyles cstyle)
{
    RWStyle currentStyle;

    switch ( cstyle )
    {
    case rw_pageheader: cstyle = rw_tableheader;
    case rw_standard: cstyle = rw_tabletext;
    case rw_tabletext:
    {    currentStyle = tableTextStyle;    }
        break;
    case rw_tableheader:
    {    currentStyle = tableHeaderStyle;    }
        break;
    case rw_redtabletext:
    {    currentStyle = redTableTextStyle;    }
        break;

    default:
        break;

    }


    QTextTable *table = m_cursor.currentTable();
    if ((! table))
    {
        freeTableLines=1;
        m_cursor.insertTable(freeTableLines, content.count(), currentStyle.tableStyle);
    }

    if  (freeTableLines==0)
    {
        table->appendRows(1);
        m_cursor.movePosition(QTextCursor::PreviousRow);
        m_cursor.movePosition(QTextCursor::NextRow);
        freeTableLines++;

    }


    for (int i=0; i<content.size(); i++)
    {
        m_cursor.setBlockFormat(currentStyle.parStyle);
        m_cursor.insertText(content[i], currentStyle.textStyle);
        m_cursor.movePosition(QTextCursor::NextCell);
    }

    freeTableLines--;
}
```

Comment: Тоже столкнулся с такой проблемой. Есть решение?

Answer (score 1):

Дробить ячейки методом `QTextTable::splitCell` можно только в том случае, если они были предварительно объединены методом `QTextTable::mergeCells`. В вашем случае необходимо именно объединять ячейки.

Возьмём таблицу с заполненными единичными ячейками:
[image: Изначальная таблица]

Метод заполнения ячейки (пример):

```
void MyClass::setCellText(QTextTable* table, int row, int col, const QString& text)
{
    cursor = table->cellAt(row,col).firstCursorPosition();
    cursor.insertText(text, textFormat);
    table->cellAt(row,col).setFormat(textFormat);
}
```

Данный код:

```
QTextTable* table = cursor.currentTable();
if (table) {
    int rows = table->rows();
    for (int i = 1; i < rows; i+=3) {
        //Ячейки объединённые по 3
        table->mergeCells(i, 0, 3, 1);
        table->mergeCells(i, 3, 3, 1);
        table->mergeCells(i, 4, 3, 1);
        //Заполняем номера
        setCellText(table, i, 0, QString::number((i-1)/3+1));
    }
    //Ячейки на весь столбец
    table->mergeCells(1, 1, rows-1, 1);
    table->mergeCells(1, 2, rows-1, 1);

    //Заполняем значения объединённых ячеек
    setCellText(table, 1, 1, "99");
    setCellText(table, 1, 2, "100");
    setCellText(table, 1, 3, "10");
    setCellText(table, 1, 4, "11");
}
```

Приведёт к следующему результату:

[image: Конечная таблица]

Принцип включения в реализацию зависит от формата исходных данных и процесса их получения.